# Need help to understand surfarray.array2d - it seems to not save color correctly

Tags: python, pygame

I did a test where I converted a Surface into an array2d, and then convert it right back, like so:

```
fg = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(pygame.surfarray.array2d(fg))
```

This is the full code (for you to copy and paste into Pygame to do a quick test if you wish):

```
pygame.init()


SURFACE_MAIN = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
fg = pygame.Surface((300, 300))
fg.fill((70, 53, 52))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                fg = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(pygame.surfarray.array2d(fg))

    SURFACE_MAIN.blit(pygame.Surface.copy(fg), (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

When you press <kbd>s</kbd> key, the original brown becomes green.

Old color: (70, 53, 52, 255)  
New color: (85, 182, 0, 255)

The solution to this turns out to be using array3d instead, but I don't understand why this is. Could someone explain it to me? Much appreciated!

Reference: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.array2d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `pygame.surfarray.make_surface` will convert a 2D-array to a surface with bit depth of 8 and a 3D-array to a surface with bit depth of 32. This matters because of how pygame handles bit depth.

### Bit depth

The bit depth is the amount of information there is to represent a color. A bit depth of 32 allow us to represent `2^32 = 4,294,967,296` colors, which is the same as assigning each color component (Red, Green, Blue, Alpha) 8-bits each (a value between 0-255).

A bit depth of 8 allow us to represent `2^8 = 256` colors. That would be 2 bits for each color component (a value between 0-3). This is however not how pygame handles colors of this bit depth.

### How pygame handles it

Pygame does not store each value for RGBA, but instead store the pixel as a single integer which can be decoded to get the values for the color components, as long as the bit depth is more than 8. When you have a lower bit depth pygame uses a color palette for the surface. Each pixel value now becomes an index to a color palette with 256 colors, instead of an encoded integer. This palette is available through the method [`surface.get_palette()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_palette) and can be set using [`surface.set_palette()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_palette).

It's this conversion that makes your color values weird. Here's a short program to demonstrate and to experiment with (use the console, start with a bit depth of 32 and your color by typing the values separated with comma and/or space):

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1, 1))

depth = int(input('\nDepth size: '))
color = [int(x) for x in input('Color: ').replace(',', ' ').split()]

surface = pygame.Surface((1, 1), depth=depth)  # Valid bit depth sizes are 8, 12, 16, 24 or 32
surface.fill(color)
print('\nSurface 1 has bit depth', surface.get_bitsize(), ' | The color is: ', surface.get_at((0, 0)))

surface2 = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(pygame.surfarray.array2d(surface))
print('\nSurface 2 has bit depth', surface2.get_bitsize(), ' | The color is: ', surface2.get_at((0, 0)))
surface2.set_palette([(123, 123, 123) for _ in range(256)])  # Set whole color palette to one color
print('Surface 2 now has the color: ', surface2.get_at((0, 0)))

surface3 = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(pygame.surfarray.array3d(surface))
print('\nSurface 3 has bit depth', surface3.get_bitsize(), ' | The color is: ', surface3.get_at((0, 0)))
print('Surface 3 has no color palette since it has a bit depth greater than 8')
```